# CSS not linking to HTML

Tags: html, css, django

I have a HTML file and a CSS file in the same directory, but when I run the project, the CSS is not loaded and just the HTML appears. Below is the HTML code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/afc/Templates/afc/afc.css">
```

I tried using just the filename, it works if I just load that particular page but when I run the project, CSS does not get loaded.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="afc.css">
```

I also tried loading using <kbd>CTRL+F5</kbd> to reload without cache, but didn't work.
EDIT:
I am getting this on the terminal:

```
Not Found: /afc/afc.css
[11/Oct/2016 18:55:30] "GET /afc/afc.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2853
```

I am using Django.

Comment: is the path `/afc/Templates/afc/afc.css` inside the document root of the website?

Comment: Yes. It is inside the root dir of the website

Comment: "when I run the project, CSS does not get loaded.": we're missing information here: what's the IDE you use? What's the run configuration?

Comment: I am developing it in Django using Pycharm. And I dont know what run configuration means.

Comment: Since this is a Django project, look at Django's static files support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's HTML files are not static: they are templates. They are not served by the static server, but interpreted by Django itself. So there is no point in putting your CSS file in "the same directory" as the HTML file; that can't possibly work.

Instead, put your CSS in the static directory and link to it using Django's `{% static %}` tag. And learn about how to deploy the static files by reading the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

"in the same directory"

But you used an "absolute" path `/afc/...`. Use a relative one `afc.css`.

---

Note that since it's HTML code, the "relative" path is relative to **the current URI**. So if the CSS file is in the same folder as the HTML, but your server is inserting redirection (ie: `RewriteRule ^/?$ /bla/bla/index.html [L]`), then you must also redirect the CSS file (`RewriteRule ^styles\.css$ /bla/bla/styles.css [L]`).

Try to access your CSS file directly: what's its URL? What's the HTML page URL? You'll then be able to set up the proper relative path.

Comment: I tried, it didn't work. It works only if load the page separately, not when I run the project.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

Comment: In what way does this help the OP?

Answer (score -1):

It should work and you don't need to use the full path if you have the css and html file in the same folder. Check for typos!